# Convert azure web application to azure website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles, azure-webjobs

Within our company we've got a rather large serviceapplication running as a azure cloudservice. The service contains a webrole and a workerrole.
The webrole contains an MVC-application and the workerrole is running in the background. The workerrole is used to handle several large processes and a bunch smaller processes 24/7, this is checked every 5 minutes.

I've created an azure website for this application and wrote a small wrapper class which checks if configuration values needs to be taken from either the web.config file or cloud configuration files (.cscfg files). I've added the appropiate transformations to transform some extra settings and published the application to the azure website.

So far everything works good, but what i've expected a bit already indeed happened.. The workerrole isn't working anymore and is throwing errors. The first error i've seen was;

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So ofcourse i've taken the quick solution and went 'properties > copy local' and set it to true. After publishing this to the azure website i'm getting the following error;

```
Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can find out where this error is coming from, but it feels like this is the second of a whole other bunch of errors coming. On several sites I've read that azure websites just doesn't support workerroles (obviously).
This gives me a few options;

1. Find a solution so I can connect the azure website to the workerrole still running in the cloudservice. If this works I can drop the webrole and I'm able to connect multiple instances to one workerrole.
2. Find a solution to convert the workerrole to something (no idea what this possibly could be) supported by the azure website.
3. Forget the whole idea and stick to the cloudservice setting with the web- and workerrole.

**Fragment from workerrole.cs**

The facade makes a database call to check any newly added processes.

```
public override void Run()
    {

        // Only process if the web.config says we're allowed to do so.
        while (true)
        {
            var process = Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Process"));
            try
            {
                if (process )
                {
                    var username = WebConfigurationManager.GetSetting("UsernameWorkerRole");
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                    {
                        var version = Assembly.Load("Ecare.Productie.WorkerRole").GetName().Version;
                        var versionString = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build.ToString("000"), version.Revision.ToString("00000"));

                        username = ApplicatieConstanten.WorkerRoleName + " " + versionString;
                    }

                    IServiceFacade serviceFacade = new ServiceFacade(username);
                    serviceFacade.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AuditingLoggingHelper.GetLoggerInstance(ApplicatieConstanten.WorkerRoleName).Error("Exception while starting service", ex);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

        // ReSharper disable once FunctionNeverReturns
    }
```

The main reason we're doing this, is because we have VS solution with an MVC-application (the web role) and the workerrole. We're currently publishing this to an cloud service in azure. Because of the development processes we're running seperate test, acceptation and production environments. Since it's a heavy process we're running quite expensive machines in azure, but that mostly only needed for the workerrole. The webpart is lightweight. So it's mainly an idea trying to reduce costs. So the idea is to convert the webrole to an azure website (this part is working already with just a small modification to read information from the web.config instead of the cloudconfiguration). But the workerrole currently isn't working because we haven't changed anything for that yet. An colleague of mine basically said "write a wrapper for the configpart, publish the azurewebsite to 1 or more testenvironments and point them to the same workerrole". But i'm having my doubts wether this is even possible..

Did anyone else ever ran into this sort of situation and found a solution for this? Any help finding a solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Though I have provided an answer below, I am a bit confused - Why are you trying to convert a Worker Role to a Web Application? Normally folks convert a Web Role to a Web Application? Worker Roles are usually converted to Web Jobs.

Comment: @guarav, i'll update the question:)

Answer (score 4):

> Find a solution so I can connect the azure website to the workerrole
>   still running in the cloudservice. If this works I can drop the
>   webrole and I'm able to connect multiple instances to one workerrole.

I'm guessing that you're using some kind of queue mechanism (Azure Storage Queues or Service Bus Queues) to facilitate communication between Web and Worker Role. If that's the case, then you can continue to use the same. Your website will push messages in a queue and your worker role will poll this queue and fetch messages and work on those.

> Find a solution to convert the workerrole to something (no idea what
>   this possibly could be) supported by the azure website.

Do take a look at [`Azure Webjobs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/). In Web Apps world, they are the counterpart of Worker Roles.

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments, I think you should be able to port your code to run as Web Jobs. There are two ways by which you can do it:

1. If you create a `Continuous Web Job`, then you would have to put this 10 second sleep logic in your code itself. The job will continuously be running but will only wake up every 10 seconds. Similar to your current Worker Role implementation.
2. You could very well take out this 10 seconds sleep logic from your code by making your Web Job as a `Scheduled Web Job` where you schedule to run this every 10 seconds. I would recommend going down this route as you have decoupled your scheduling logic (10 second sleep) from your application. So tomorrow if you were to increase the sleep time, you would simply change the schedule in the portal without redeploying your code.

Comment: Well actually we're not using a queue system. We workerrole.cs file contains a while(true)-loop. Within the loop we're checking if there are any  processes / messages to be handled, if so they're started. If not we're doing a thread.sleep (10 secs for now) after which the while loop continues.

I'll take a deeper look into the azure webjobs:)

Comment: How are you checking if there are any processes / messages to be handled?

Comment: @Guarav, see the piece of code i've just added for this.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the code and if I understand correctly, basically it's a setting in your config file which indicates if worker role should process the task or not. If this setting is false, then worker role doesn't process anything, sleeps for 10 seconds and then checks again. If this setting is true, then worker role process the task and then sleeps for 10 seconds and checks again. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: @Guarav, thanks for the update! Looks like web jobs indeed is the way to go then. I'll take this option into consideration and discuss it with the rest of the team. Thanks for the good information on this one! Will be continued

Answer (score 3):

As Gaurav pointed, the equivalent to worker roles in the App Service space is [Azure WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).

Regarding this problem:

> So far everything works good, but what i've expected a bit already indeed happened.. The workerrole isn't working anymore and is throwing errors. The first error i've seen was;
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> So ofcourse i've taken the quick solution and went 'properties > copy local' and set it to true. After publishing this to the azure website i'm getting the following error;
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` is specific to Cloud Services, and will not work in Web Apps (that's why you get the `msshrtmi` error with the web app). If you are still running a worker role, that file is in the instance GAC, and should be in your local machine's also. That said, `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` can be referenced in the worker role project, but not the web app project.

I'm guessing you are using ServiceRuntime to get some configuration setting value using:

```
var value = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(settingName);
```

You can changed it to:

```
var value = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(settingName);
```

as this method reads the configuration setting value from the appropriate configuration store ([from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.getsetting.aspx)).

Comment: "That said, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime can be referenced in the worker role project, but not the web app project." Good point since I referenced it with copy output = true in the webapp project. I'll try the same in the workerrole project to see what happens:)

Answer (score 0):

The **best** solution here is to convert the Worker Role to a WebJob as @Graurav mentioned above.

If you want to connect the Web App to the Worker Role would be to use an Azure Queue or other intermediary storage where operations could be dropped form the WebApp and picked up by the Worker Role.